# Верстка страницы с дивами

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Добрый день! У меня вопрос, как сверстать страницу с 4-мя дивами, два блока, а под ними еще два блока. И чтобы ширина общего дива была резиновая, а внутренние дивы растягивались, в зависимости от ширины общего дива. Вот сделал два варианта верстки, но они оба с фиксированной шириной, что очень мне не нравится...

[Вариант первый](http://jsfiddle.net/wm8K2/)

[Вариант второй](http://jsfiddle.net/JY2mE/)

Comment: [так](http://jsfiddle.net/wm8K2/2/) ?

Comment: да, eicto. Так! Спасибо! Сформируй ответ, отмечу как верный.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не учитываете тех несчастных, у которых до сих пор осел седьмой и, не дай Бог, ниже седьмой версий, то можно [сделать таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ty5xp/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">1</div>
        <div class="td">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr">
        <div class="td">3</div>
        <div class="td">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.tr {
    display: table-row;
}
.td {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #060;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: а если без имитации тегов таблицы нельзя никак сделать? Используя средства выравнивания и позиционирования, как я делал в примере с фиксированной шириной.

Comment: да, тут табличная разметка более подходит )

Comment: tr не надо вроде :)

Comment: а не вру, надо, там же две строки

Comment: просто мне сказали без табличных тегов сформировать такую штуку. И что в IE не пашет пример Deonis как надо это тоже плохо конечно(

Comment: @IntegralAL, а где вы тут видите табличные теги? )) Тут CSS и не больше. Ну, вот вам [еще вариант][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/ty5xp/1/

Comment: Нет, не смущает). А второй вариант кстати у меня почему отображается див под дивом, а не по два блока на странице. Спасибо, за ответ!

Comment: хак для `display: inline-block;` в ie7:

`display: -moz-inline-stack;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
zoom: 1;`

Comment: @NoName, точно точно... я и забыл, что ослина ниже восьмой, тоже нормально не работает с inline-block ))